# ASP.NET Copying Records From Excel to SQL Server- Slow Performance

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, sqlbulkcopy

I'm using ASP.NET and SqlBulkCopy to copy records from an Excel file that the user uploads to the site to Sql Server. The average number of rows is around 50. I'm using Windows server 2016. The code below has worked fine for years but has recently become very slow and often times out and the only way to fix it is to restart IIS.  I wanted to ask if there is a way to optimize this code or if it could be causing a memory leak?  Do you have any suggestions on how to improve it.. Thanks

```vb
Sub ImportFile(ByVal FileName As String)
    Try

        If fileuploadExcel.FileName <> "" Then
            Dim path = fileuploadExcel.PostedFile.FileName
            Dim tableName As String = "PCAReviews_Upload"
            Dim extension As String = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(fileuploadExcel.PostedFile.FileName)
            Dim excelConnectionString As String
            Dim conn As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection(connStr)

            excelConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=E:\Users\FileUploads\" & FileName & ";Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;Persist Security Info=False"
            
    Dim excelConnection As OleDbConnection = New OleDbConnection(excelConnectionString)
            conn.Open()

            Dim comm As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand("truncate table " & tableName, conn)
            Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand("SELECT Workgroup, [Last Name],  [First Name], [Titanium Number], [Phone Number], [Inbound-Outbound], [Date of the Call], [Time of the Call], [Duration of the Call], ID FROM [PCA_Sample_Temp$]", excelConnection)

            excelConnection.Open()

            Dim dr As OleDbDataReader
            dr = cmd.ExecuteReader()

            Dim sqlBulk As SqlBulkCopy = New SqlBulkCopy(connStr)

            'Set the destination table name
            sqlBulk.DestinationTableName = tableName
            sqlBulk.WriteToServer(dr)
            excelConnection.Close()
            excelConnection.Dispose()
            conn.Close()
            lblMessage.ForeColor = Drawing.Color.Green
            lblMessage.Text = "Import was successful!<br />"

        Else
            lblMessage.ForeColor = Drawing.Color.Red
            lblMessage.Text = "Please select Excel file to upload"
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        lblMessage.Text = ex.Message
        lblMessage.ForeColor = Drawing.Color.Red
    End Try

End Sub
```

Comment: After restarting IIS, is the performance of the loading OK again?

Comment: Yes, after restarting IIS, the performance is fast/normal again but seems to degrade after a few days and then eventually stops working completely. By "not working" I mean it won't copy the records at all and just spins indefinitely. Thanks

Comment: Is the SqlConnection pooling disabled (in the connection string)? is the try throwing any exceptions? Preferably the connections are inside using blocks https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/using-statement
To try and improve performance, for SqlBulkCopy use WriteToServerAsync instead of the Sync method https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy.writetoserverasync?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1

Comment: There are a number of objects not being cleaned up/disposed of (sqlBulk is never disposed, the connections aren't dispose of in the event of an exception). I'd start with that first and foremost. The TRUNCATE TABLE command seems redundant btw as it's not used.

Comment: A slight side point, but if the number of rows you are dealing with is "low" (up to 1000s), then a TVP approach can give better performance (not necessarily noticeable in the grand scheme of things for low volumes - but an option for smaller loads when SqlBulkCopy isn't really needed). I blogged the detail here: https://www.sentryone.com/blog/sqlbulkcopy-vs-table-valued-parameters-bulk-loading-data-into-sql-server.

Either your app code is the issue (hence my prev q re: IIS restart resolving it or not & first step to ensure objects are disposed), or, there's some blocking going on in the DB